# Dependency Injection with inheritance and Generics in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following minimal, reproducible example.

```
public class BaseEntity{}    
public class BaseChildClass: BaseEntity{}    
public class ChildA : BaseChildClass {}
public class ChildB : BaseChildClass {}

public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity{}

public class DataRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity{}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        if (ChildAFeature) // loaded from config
        {
          services.AddScoped<IRepository<BaseChildClass>, DataRepository<ChildA>>();
        }
        else
        {
          services.AddScoped<IRepository<BaseChildClass>, DataRepository<ChildB>>();
        }

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        
        var service = provider.GetService<BaseChildClass>();
        
        Console.WriteLine(service.GetType());
    }
}
```

The problem is when trying to inject service like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<BaseChildClass>, DataRepository<ChildA>>();
```

Compile error shows

> there is no implicit convertion from  DataRepository<ChildA> to
> IRepository<BaseChildClass>

I need to inject either `ChildA` or `ChildB` to the repository depending on a feature flag. So basically, some times I need childA repo and sometimes childB repo based on a condition.

Comment: Why would you even do that? If you want to use the concrete implementation `ChildA` then that is what should be requested: `services.AddScoped<IRepository<ChildA>, DataRepository<ChildA>>();`

Comment: For entities in modern OOP, base classes are usually a code smell used to provide a toolkit of functions. In that case, use composition and smaller classes instead. Just a heads up :)

Also, if something requesting the base type cant act upon all subtypes, you are violating liskovs substation principle.

Comment: @DavidG, i need to inject either childA or childB to the repo depending on a feature flag. So basically, some times I need childA repo and sometimes childB repo based on a condition.

Comment: Where does the feature flag come from? If it's `IConfiguration` then just add an `if` black around the `services.AddScoped` line.

Comment: @DavidG That is basically what i am doing in my real solution, but having this convertion error

Comment: But if you get this working, how would you expect the class that received this object to use it?

Comment: Injecting IRepository<BaseChildClass> in the receiving class.

Comment: I get that, but how would that receiver use it? Surely it needs to know about ChildA or ChildB?

Comment: The idea is to set up either childA or childB to IRepository<BaseChildClass> on startup, based on an azure feature flag

Comment: @alvardo I think you are looking at the problem from the wrong perspective, look for interfaces to solve your problem easily.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the service registrations in the wrong way.

Updated your dot-net fiddle [Fiddle Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1yATgt).

Here's the way to register generic dependencies.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(DataRepository<>));
    services.AddScoped<BaseChildClass, ChildA>();
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    
    var repo = provider.GetService<IRepository<ChildA>>();

    Console.WriteLine(repo.GetType());
    
    var service = provider.GetService<BaseChildClass>();
    
    Console.WriteLine(service.GetType());
}
```

Comment: I usually implement something as you suggested. But for this particular project, I need to inject DataRepository<ChildA>or DataRepository<ChildB> to IRepository<BaseChildClass> depending on a feature flag.

Comment: Then use a AddScoped overload for registering BaseChildClass that takes a func<>. And in the func check the condition and return the fitting instance.

Comment: @Ralf I Tried it, but still giving me the convertion error

Comment: Updated Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/PwrTBt

Comment: But what we need to inject based on the condition is the repo. something like this based on your example.https://dotnetfiddle.net/AqVtpI

Answer (score -1):

Generic parameters don't really work with inheritance.

You can however declare the T in the interface as `<out T>`, then your use case should work. This does however force you to only use T as a return value, not as an input value. You can take a look at how `IEnumerable<T>` is declared, it does this too.